# How to add values in spinner in android with array

Tags: java, android

How to add values in spinner in android form with array connected to text file in remote host ?
This code print FATAL EXCEPTION: main .... can you help me?
Any help would be appreciated .............

```
03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxx.xxxxx/com.xxxxx.xxxxx.SpinnerPopText}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4935)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.SpinnerPopText.onCreate(SpinnerPopText.java:37)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
    03-09 23:29:23.321: E/AndroidRuntime(3204):     ... 11 more
```

java class

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.app.Activity;

public class SpinnerPopText extends Activity {

    Spinner sp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinnerpoptext);

                String path = "http://www.myhost.com/public/country.txt";
                URL u = null;
                try {
                    u = new URL(path);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u
                            .openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.connect();
                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    in.read(buffer);
                    bo.write(buffer);


                            final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
                            list.add(bo.toString());


                            final Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                            adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            sp.setAdapter(adp);
(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            try {
                                bo.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're running network code on your main thread. You should move this into an AsyncTask or similar

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to make network things on main thread.

So either use AsyncTask and do your work on doinbackground then update your spinner in postExecute.

Or use a thread to do your network work then inside the thread call runOnUIThread and do your spinner work.